Using get_tree to create a timer but it's not activating
I'm working on creating Pong and I have two RayCast2Ds on the left and right side of the arena. I have it so whenever one of the RayCast gets hit, the ball resets back to the middle of the arena and the opposite player gets a point. I'm trying to make it so after the ball hits the RayCast, it resets back to the middle of the arena, pauses for 3s and starts the next round. I've added the code inside the if statement for gaining a point but for some reason the timer won't start.
func _physics_process(delta):
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        if (!already_collided):
            already_collided = true
            $Ball.position.x = 575
            $Ball.position.y = 350
            Globals.p2_score += 1
            $Label2.text = str(Globals.p2_score)
            await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout #timer
        else:
            already_collided = false
        
    if $RayCast2D2.is_colliding():
        if (!already_collided):
            already_collided = true
            $Ball.position.x = 575
            $Ball.position.y = 350
            Globals.p1_score += 1
            $Label.text = str(Globals.p1_score)
            await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout #timer
        else:
            already_collided = false


I think your time is created and working. It just don't pause any other loop.
You can verify that if you place a print in front of the timer and after it. You will see, that the second log will be printed after 3 seconds, while your game loop is running.
Without knowing your code I can just guess, but I assume your ball just has a movement logic, which runs as soon the ball is in the scene.
You could add an "paused" flag, which stops the ball if true:
#Ball Script assuming the movement code sits in physics process
var paused : bool = false    
func _physics_process(delta):
   if paused:
      return  #do nothing as long the paused variable is set
   #your movement logic

Now with that flag you could raycast logic can be extended to look like this:
func _physics_process(delta):
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        if (!already_collided):
            already_collided = true
            $Ball.paused = true #pause ball before repositioning
            $Ball.position.x = 575
            $Ball.position.y = 350
            Globals.p2_score += 1
            $Label2.text = str(Globals.p2_score)
            await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout #timer
            $Ball.paused = false #start movement after 3 seconds
        else:
            already_collided = false
        
    if $RayCast2D2.is_colliding():
        if (!already_collided):
            already_collided = true 
            $Ball.paused = true
            $Ball.position.x = 575
            $Ball.position.y = 350
            Globals.p1_score += 1
            $Label.text = str(Globals.p1_score)
            await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout #timerv
            $Ball.paused = false
        else:
            already_collided = false

Or just create a reset_ball function in your ball script to make your code cleaner:
func reset_ball():
    paused = true
    position.x = 575
    position.y = 350
    await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout #timerv
    paused = false

and call this when colliding:
func _physics_process(delta):
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        if (!already_collided):
            already_collided = true
            Globals.p2_score += 1
            $Label2.text = str(Globals.p2_score)
            $Ball.reset_ball()
        else:
            already_collided = false
#...

